# Chrome not handling "308 - Permanent Redirect" redirects as expected on HTTPS

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, redirect, https, sinatra

I am running a web server on Sinatra behind an Nginx reverse proxy server. It is a requirement that HTTP requests are all redirected to HTTPS, so that is my current configuration.

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {                                            
    default Upgrade;                                                               
    '' close;                                                                      
}                                                                                  

## Listen on port 80 for HTTP requests, redirect to https                          
server {                                                       
    listen 80 default;                                                             
    listen [::]:80 default;                                                        
    return 308 https://$host$request_uri;                                          
}                                                                                  


## Use HTTPS when requests are made                                                
server {                                                                           
  listen 443 ssl;                                                                  

  # don't allow old ssl protocols                                                  
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;                                             

  # ensure that our ciphers are preferred, and give a list of preferred ciphers    
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;                                                    
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;        

  # enable session tickets                                                         
  ssl_session_tickets on;                                                          

  # TLS session cache 4 hours, 40 MB                                               
  ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:40m;                                              
  ssl_session_timeout 4h;                                                          

  ssl_certificate /data/projects/cloudpeel-next/cloudpeel.crt;                     
  ssl_certificate_key /data/projects/cloudpeel-next/cloudpeel.key;                 

  location / {                                                                     
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4567;                                              
    proxy_http_version 1.1;                                                        
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;                                        
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;                               
    proxy_set_header Host $host;                                                   
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                                      
  }                                                                                
}
```

This works great in most cases, except when a POST request occurs from the client. Ideally the 308 (or 307) redirect is supposed to preserve the POST data and request the client again to request a different address (in this case the HTTPS version of the site).

However, what occurs in Chrome, is that the request is handled (as far as I can tell more like a 301 redirect, and the request is interpreted as GET, for which my backend has different behavior, redirecting the user to an incorrect page.

I have tried using return 301 and 307, with neither producing the desired results.

The curious thing, is that when tested in Edge and Firefox, the application works exactly as expected.

The network tab in the developer shows the following: a 303 code for a POST attempt and a 308 GET, which is not the desired behavior. In Firefox, only code 200 is shown. Is there anything I can do about this in my Nginx configuration?

**Edit:** I tried changing my redirect in Nginx to 301, and Firefox still works as intended, while Chrome is still broken.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out my problem. I edited my `location / {}` block and here is what finally got it working for me - hope it helps someone!

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default Upgrade;
        '' close;
}

## Listen on port 80 for HTTP requests, redirect to https
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


## Use HTTPS when requests are made
server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  # don't allow old ssl protocols
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

  # ensure that our ciphers are preferred, and give a list of preferred ciphers
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

  # enable session tickets
  ssl_session_tickets on;

  # TLS session cache 4 hours, 40 MB
  ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:40m;
  ssl_session_timeout 4h;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cloudpeel.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/cloudpeel.key;

  location / {

    #HTTPS Config
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-SSL on;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:4567;
    #WebSocket config
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

  }
}
```